# Microsoft information protection SDK 1.7.133 - Load library failed issue error

Tags: microsoft-information-protection

I was using MIP SDK 1.6 before and I initialised MIP by providing Path. It was working fine.
I upgraded to 1.7 version  and now its failing with the Load library failed error.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"LoadLibrary
> failed for:
> [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\teststs\bin\x64\mip_dotnet.dll]",
> "ExceptionType":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","StackTrace":"
> at
> Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.SafeNativeMethods.LoadLibrary(String
> dllToLoad)\r\n  at
> Microsoft.InformationProtection.Utils.Loader.LoadDlls(String
> dllFolder, String dllName, String[] dllDependencies)\r\n  at
> Microsoft.InformationProtection.MIP.Initialize(MipComponent
> mipComponent, String path)\r\n

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share how you are building the path and setting it in MipContext? Something like this should still work. I've tested this in a .NET project on MIP SDK 1.7.133.

```
// Set path to bins folder.
var path = Path.Combine(
            Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)).FullName,
            Environment.Is64BitProcess ? "bin\\x64" : "bin\\x86");

// Initialize MIP for File API.  
MIP.Initialize(MipComponent.File, path);
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I am using  the same path as you mentioned here . But is is  still failing for me.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Is it failing in your local dev environment, or does it only fail when deployed?

Comment: It works fine with localhost but fails after deployment  with the above error. If I lower the version to 1.6.152 then it works fine after deployment as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you share the OS/IIS version you're using  when it fails?

Comment: I've been able to repro this issue on my end. I found that the VC++ runtime wasn't installed. However, it failed on both 1.6 and 1.7 without it. With the runtime installed, it seems to work.

Can you validate that the runtime is installed on the server and that you're deploying in release mode?

Comment: I deployed in Release mode and it is working  fine. Thank you for your help and time .  Can you please tell me ,  1.6 version works in Debug mode and 1.7 does not. Why this difference ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. There may be a difference in the build between the two. Typically, building in debug mode requires the debug version of the VC++ runtime, which is included only in Visual Studio AFAIK. As to what changed between the debug builds in 1.6 and 1.7, I will see if I can find out.

Comment: Thank you @Tom for all your help